# Exploit temporal information in GCN for the Elliptic dataset

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, graph-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the results obtained on the [Elliptic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ellipticco/elliptic-data-set) from [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02591) (the EvolveGCN) and [[2]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361357354_Graph-Based_LSTM_for_Anti-money_Laundering_Experimenting_Temporal_Graph_Convolutional_Network_with_Bitcoin_Data) using PyTorch geometric and PyTorch Geometric temporal libraries.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find any useful implementation that works with dynamic datasets (datasets that change their structure over time, i.e. number of nodes and number of edges). The only example codes I found are related to datasets that only change feature values over time, but the structure remains the same.

Does someone can give me a good hint or a resource to help me on this path?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a comment here: A classic GCN (I don't know the specific temporal variants) can be applied to graphs of any size. Consider e.g. the first layer computing $\sigma(\tilde{A}XW_1)$. Here your weight matrix $W_1$ only depends on the feature dimension and not on the number of nodes or edges. Thus, if you are given a (trained) GCN (e.g. the PyTorch geometric implementation), you should be able to apply it to any other graph out-of-the-box without any code changes even if the graph structure changes.